# Generic Array Method Class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I've been trying to turn this generic arraylist class into an array but I haven't been able to get it to work. I've hit a roadblock at the push() and pop() methods. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the original class:

```
public class GenericStack<E> {
  private java.util.ArrayList<E> list = new java.util.ArrayList<E>();

  public int getSize() {
    return list.size();
  }

  public E peek() {
    return list.get(getSize() - 1);
  }

  public E push(E o) {
    list.add(o);
    return o;
  }

  public E pop() {
    E o = list.get(getSize() - 1);
    list.remove(getSize() - 1);
    return o;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return list.isEmpty();
  }
}
```

And here's my revised class so far:

```
public class GenericStack<E> {
    public static int size = 16;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private E[] list = (E[])new Object[size];

  public void add(int index, E e) {
      ensureCapacity();

      for (int i = size - 1; i >= index; i--) {
          list[i + 1] = list[i];

      list[index] = e;

      size++;   
    }
  }
  public int getLength() {
    return list.length;
  }

  public E peek() {
      E o = null;
      o = list[0];
      return o;
  }
  public E push(E o) {
      ensureCapacity();
      list.append(o);
        size++;
        return o;
  }
  public E pop() {
      E o = null;
      for (int i = 0; i > list.length; i++) {
          o = list[i - 1];
    }
        list[list.length - 1] = null;
        size--;
        return o;
      }
  private void ensureCapacity() {
      if (size >= list.length) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        E[] newlist = (E[])(new Object[size * 2 + 1]);
          System.arraycopy(list, 0, newlist, 0, size);
          list = newlist;
      }
  }
  public boolean isEmpty() {
      if (list.length > 0) {
        return false;
      }
      else {
          return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: For starters, an array has no `append()` method. you have to assign to the appropriate index like: `list[size++] = o;`

Comment: And if you know size, you don't have to iterate through your list. `o = list[size-1]; list[--size] = null; return o;` will do. Note that the length of your underlying `list` array is not the size of your GenericStack.

Comment: It's recommended to use name method like of official `Stack` class, so there are 5 methods: `empty()`  `peek()`  `pop()`  `push(E item)`  `search(Object o)`

Answer (score 0):

NB: You must first correct your code like mentioned in comments.

- It's recommended to use name method like of official Stack class, so there are 5 methods: `empty()` `peek()` `pop()` `push(E item)` `search(Object o)`.
- You should declare initial size of your array as a constant and an other variable for current size and all your attributes should be **`private`** like that:

  ```
  private final int MAX_SIZE = 16;
  private int currentSize=0;
  ```

There is the code of **peek()** method:

```
public E peek() {
      E o = null;
      o = list[currentSize-1];
      return o;
}
```

There is the code of **push(E o)** method:

```
 public E push(E o) {
  list[currentSize]=o;
  currentSize++;
    return o;
```

}

There is the code of **pop()** method this method must throw `EmptyStackException` - if this stack is empty:

```
 public E pop() {
  E o = null;
  if(currentSize>0){
      o=list[currentSize - 1];
    list[currentSize - 1] = null;
    currentSize--;
    return o;
  }else{
      throw new EmptyStackException();
  }

  }
```

There is the code of **empty()** method:

```
public boolean empty() {
  if (currentSize > 0) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
      return true;
    }
   }
```